# OpenGL ES and snapshot

Tags: ios, image-processing, opengl-es, drawing

```
_eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer*) self.layer;
_eaglLayer.opaque = YES;
_eaglLayer.drawableProperties = @{kEAGLDrawablePropertyRetainedBacking : @(NO), kEAGLDrawablePropertyColorFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8 };
....
...
```

Transparent background glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);

```
- (void)render:(CADisplayLink*)displayLink {

[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context];

static float time = 0;
time += displayLink.duration * attractorIndexes.count*2;

if(startVoice)
    [self changeTRMatrixFar];
//else
//    [self changeTRMatrixNear];

glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glEnable(GL_POINT_SPRITE_OES);
glEnable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);

glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_COLOR, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_COLOR);

glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glViewport(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

glUseProgram(programHandle);
```

When I do a snapshot, I get a UIImage, if I convert it to JPEG and save to a file I get a white square, if you keep in PNG is also getting a blank square with a transparent background, and if I bring it to the screen snapshot (recorded on video end) [video](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dsmhmwteenc2c6o/attractor_alpha.m4v)
Background for some reason is not clear, and some translucent figure ..

And if I bring this snapshot on a background:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(backgroundImage.size, NO, 1.0);
context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextDrawImage(context, backgroundRect, backgroundImage.CGImage);
CGContextDrawImage(context, figureRect, attractorSnapshot.CGImage);
...
```

I get color distortion and just do some extra artifacts: [image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tr3giw4w1ekx2k2/result.png)

I can not understand what's wrong?

Comment: snapshot do teaches [Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1704/_index.html)

Comment: If you're using glReadPixels(), make sure you run that before the content is presented to the screen or you'll just get an empty result.

Comment: Yes, it is, I used it before.